# Control sum from input boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, controls

I'm trying to make some controls in Javascript when I submit a form in HTML.

Evertyhing works perfectly except the one that needs to check the sum of 2 fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validation()
{
var count=0;
if((document.getElementsByName("people")[0].selectedIndex) == "")
    {alert("How many PEOPLE?"); count++;}
else if((document.getElementsByName("amount")[0].selectedIndex) == "")
    {alert("AMOUNT has to be at least 1."); count++;}
else if((document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value) == "")
    {alert("DEPOSIT cannot be empty."); count++;}
else if((document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value) < "20")
    {alert("DEPOSIT must be at least 20."); count++;}
else if((document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value) == "")
    {alert("Mark 0 in TO PAY if they dont have to pay more."); count++;}
else if( (  (document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value) + (document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value) ) < "40")
    {alert("The minimum price of this product is 40"); count++;}

else if((document.getElementsByName("seller")[0].value) == "")
    {alert("Who is the SELLER?"); count++;}
else if(isNaN(document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value))
    {alert("TO PAY must be a number"); count++;}
else if(isNaN(document.getElementsByName("people")[0].value))
    {alert("PEOPLE must be a number"); count++;}
else if(isNaN(document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value))
    {alert("DEPOSIT must be a number"); count++;}
else if(isNaN(document.getElementsByName("amount")[0].value))
    {alert("AMOUNT must be a number"); count++;}
return (count==0);
}
</script>
```

The one that I'm not able to solve is:

```
else if( (((document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value) + (document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value)) < "40)")
    {alert("The minimum price of this product is 40"); count++;}
```

I want it to check if (deposit + topay) < 40. I noticed that with this code it is just checking if (deposit < 40) and I don't understand why.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '+' operator acts as concatenation operator in a conditional statement(or generally performs concatenation).

Hence to make it perform addition operation use,

```
else if( ((parseInt(document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value) + parseInt(document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value)) < 40))
    {alert("The minimum price of this product is 40"); count++;}
```

Answer (score 1):

> var abc = parseInt(
>   (document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value)+(document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value)
>   )         if( abc < "40" ) {          alert("h"+abc);         }

Answer (score 0):

change your if condition to this

```
if( (((document.getElementsByName("deposit")[0].value) + (document.getElementsByName("topay")[0].value)) < 40))
```